# What is a non-vanishing tangent vector field?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I’m trying to solve some exercises from Munkres’ Topology book.

In section 58, exercise 10-(d) asks to prove the following

> If $S^n$ has a non-vanishing tangent vector field $v$, then $n$ is odd. (Hint : If $v$ exists, show that the identity map is homotopic to the antipodal map)

I know what ‘non-vanishing’ and ‘vector field on $S^n$’ are.

A vector field on $S^n$ is a continuous map $S^n \to R^{n+1}$.

A non-vanishing vector field is a vector field which has no zeros.

But I’m not familiar with ‘tangent’.

I think Munkres didn’t write what it is.

Maybe $v$ is a non-vanishing tangent vector field on $S^n$ means $v(x)$ and $x$ are orthogonal? So $v$ has a tangent vector as its function value continuously?

If it is right, how can I find a homotopy between the identity map and the antipodal map?

Thanks!

Comment: A vector field on $S^n$ is not a continuous map $S^n \rightarrow R^{n+1}$, it is a map from $S^n$ to its tangent bundle so that each point gets mapped to a vector in its tangent space. If you want to phrase this as a map into $R^{n+1}$ you will have to add extra conditions (the orthogonality conditions you mentioned). A tangent vector field is the same thing as a vector field. It is emphasizing that the vectors live in the tangent spaces.

Comment: This book seems to require a vector field to be continuous. So I thought every vector field is defined to be continuous. But sorry I don’t know what tangent bundle is. Does it mean just satisfying orthogonality condition?  thanks!

Comment: @Matthew Leingang Wow, $(cos(t))x$ is a very good technique. Thanks!

Comment: @anadad: At a single point, the tangent plane is generated by vectors that are tangent to curves within the sphere that pass through that point.  If you take the union of all of those tangent planes at all the points of the sphere, you get the tangent bundle.  Tangent vector fields can be defined abstractly, but in the case of $S^n$ embedded in $R^{n+1}$, it is exactly what you surmised: a map $v \colon S^n \to R^{n+1}$ such that $v(x) \cdot x = 0$ for all $x \in S^n$.